# ASP.NET length and width of page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is there a way to establish how many pixels there is in total (length and width) for a web page generated by ASP.NET.  I am not referring to the screen resolution of the clients browser.

I have a webpage (.aspx) that varies in size (length and width) depending on parameters submitted on the results returned and I am trying to capture the height and width of the screen.

I know that JavaScript DOM has clientheight and clientwidth properties but they are consistent every time regardless of how much data is on the page.

Comment: Am I missing something? The Height and Width of the screen are going to be the client height and client width properties...

Comment: The clientheight and clientwidth properties hold the same values every time the page opens.  I am looking for values that vary depending on how much data is on the page.

Comment: That entirely depends on the viewport size. You will get a different answer for an iPhone from a iPad from a high res display... What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to capture a web page (accessed from a desktop) and save it as an image file.  This is an internal intranet application.  However, in order to specify the length and height of the image, I need to know the length and height of the webpage (the entire web page i.e. not just the parts that you can see).

Comment: @w0051977 - Why not ask about that then? Or even better - search this site - that question has been asked and answered before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html+image+c%23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try scrollWidth and scrollHeight of the body element.